# mips program can't figure out mips/mflo/sw

Tags: assembly, mips

I wanted to write a program that converts a decimal in to binary. For this I would use an array. Please look at the line commented below and tell me why it might not work because the spim simulator says attempting to execute non-instruction

```
       .text
       .globl __start
    __start:

        la $a0,prompt
        li $v0,4
        syscall

        li $v0,5
        syscall

        move $t1,$v0

        li $t0,0
        la $t2,bin
        #add $t2,$t2,124
            lop:    
            div $t1,$t1,2
        mflo $v0
        sw $v0,($t2) #right here
        add $t2,$t2,4
        add $t0,$t0,1
        ble $t0,32,lop
        j dnn

            ads:    
            la $a0,spc
    li $v0,4
    syscall
    j back

            dnn: 
        la $t0,bin
        li $t3,1
        la $a0,pr2
        li $v0,4
        syscall
        add $t0,$t0,124
            lp2:
        lw $t1,($t0)
        sub $t0,$t0,4
        add $t3,$t3,1
        move $a0,$t1
        li $v0,5
        syscall
        div $t4,$t3,4
        mflo $t4
        ble $t4,0,ads
            back:   
            ble $t3,33,lp2

        li $v0,10
        syscall

        .data
            prompt: .asciiz "Enter decimal: "
            spc:    .asciiz " "
            pr2:    .asciiz "\nbinary value:\n"
            bin:    .space 128
```

EDIT: I made some changes, like now all the 'add's are 'addi's and '.align 2' comes after .data
also in The spim simulator (PCSpim) I noticed something interesting:

```
   [0x00400020]        0x3c011001  lui $1, 4097 [bin]              ; 15: la $t2,bin
   [0x00400024]        0x342a0022  ori $10, $1, 34 [bin]
   [0x00400028]        0x34010002  ori $1, $0, 2                   ; 17: div $t1,$t1,2
   [0x0040002c]        0x0121001a  div $9, $1
   [0x00400030]        0x00004812  mflo $9
   [0x00400034]        0x00001012  mflo $2                         ; 18: mflo $v0
   [0x00400038]        0xad420000  sw $2, 0($10)                   ; 19: sw $v0,($t2)
```

why is mflo done twice?

Comment: Does it say the same thing if you change it to `sw $v0, 0($t2)`?

Comment: Also, shouldn't your add's be addi?

Comment: This has many errors. Please fix the other errors so we can try this... And specify what simulator you're using.

Comment: @Ivan Yes. I tried it that way it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @m0skito I was using spim simulator although I would like to write code as it should be on the real deal. what does addi have to do with anything the program is written the way I usually write programs except for the mflo and array part. What other errors are there?

Comment: Ah, I suppose add can use immediate values according to MIPs.  That's a pretty odd decision choice in the spec if you ask me.


Also, when I ran your program in MIPs, I received the following error: `Error in asdfsf.asm line 20: Runtime exception at 0x00400038: store address not aligned on word boundary 0x10010022`.  The line is your `sw` line.

Comment: It appears that the label `bin:` is not aligned on a word boundary. You need an `.align 2` directive before `bin:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mflo` is done twice because the [`DIV` pseudo instruction does it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture#Pseudo_instructions) and you're doing it explicitly right after.

You can just do:

```
    div $v0,$t1,2
```